# Confusing regarding a nested radical equation

Tags: solution-verification, radicals, nested-radicals, radical-equations

Consider the following

> For all $a\in\Bbb R$ solve the equation
> $$\sqrt{x^2+4a^2\sqrt{x+a}}=x+2a$$

It is immediate to see that we got the restriction $x\geqslant-a$ (even though not given I assume that this equation is meant only for $x\in\Bbb R$ aswell). However, squaring twice gives
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{x^2+4a^2\sqrt{x+a}}&=x+2a\\
x^2+4a^2\sqrt{x+a}&=x^2+4a^2+4ax\\
a\sqrt{x+a}&=x+a\\
a^2(x+a)&=(x+a)^2\tag1\\
a^2&=x+a\tag2
\end{align*}
From $(1)$ we get that $x_1=-a$ is a possible solution and assuming that $x\neq-a$ we may divide by $(x+a)$ to obtain $x_2=a(a-1)$ as second possibility.

Hence we applied a non-equivalent transformation we are forced to check our derived solutions. Thus, we get for $x_1=-a$
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{(-a)^2+4a^2\sqrt{-a+a}}&=-a+2a\\
\sqrt{a^2}&=a\\
|a|&=a
\end{align*}
Which only holds for $a\geqslant0$. For $x_2=a(a-1)$ we get
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{(a(a-1))^2+4a^2\sqrt{a(a-1)+a}}&=a(a-1)+2a\\
\sqrt{a^4-2a^3+a^2+4a^2|a|}&=a(a+1)
\end{align*}
First we may assume $a\geqslant0$ again from where we conclude
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{a^4-2a^3+a^2+4a^3}&=a(a+1)\\
\sqrt{a^4+2a^3+a^2}&=a(a+1)\\
\sqrt{a^2(a+1)^2}&=a(a+1)\\
|a(a+1)|&=a(a+1)
\end{align*}
The last line holds since $a\geqslant0\implies a(a+1)\geqslant0$. On the other hand from $a<0$ we get
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{a^4-2a^3+a^2-4a^3}&=a(a+1)\\
\sqrt{a^4-6a^3+a^2}&=a(a+1)\\
|a|\sqrt{a^2-6a+1}&=a(a+1)\\
\sqrt{a^2-6a+1}&=-a-1
\end{align*}
But I am not sure how to interpret this result. Apparently it does not hold for $a=-1$, which matches the given restriction, but I am not sure whether this is sufficient to show that this is a contradiction.

I was told that the solution is given by $x=-a$ and $a=0$. This would basically mean that there is only the trivial solution $(x,a)=(0,0)$. However, since I cannot spot a mistake above I am certainly sure that the second restriction, $a=0$, is nonsense and I do not see how it could be derived. Moreover if I am not mistaken the pair $(x,a)=(-5,5)$ works perfectly well too (choosing the positive square root of $25$). I thought about somehow combining $x\geqslant-a$ and $a\geqslant0$ to obtain $a=0$ but I do not see how.

> Could someone explain me what I am missing? Is my solution correct or is it in need of improvement?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Notice that for $a=0$ all non-negative reals are solutions.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Thus the set of solutions is maximal?

Comment: In what sense of "maximal"?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe As for $a=0$ the solely restriction for $x$ is to be a positive real number, whereas for *any* $a>0$ we are restricted to *two* specific values of $x$. Thus, the set of solutions for $a=0$ is somewhat the largest possible.

Comment: Indeed.  But to stay correct, $x$ may be non-negative if $a=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Squaring the equation (which might introduce extra solutions), we have

$$x^2+4a^2\sqrt{x+a}=x^2+4ax+4a^2,$$
or
$$a=0\lor a\sqrt{x+a}=x+a.$$

$a=0$ reduces the equation to $|x|=x$, or $x\ge0$.

Otherwise, as $x+a\ge0$, a solution is only possible with $a>0$ and is given by

$$\sqrt{x+a}=0\lor\sqrt{x+a}=a,$$ i.e.

$$x=-a\lor x=a^2-a.$$ If you plug these values in the original equation, they are compatible.

To summarize:

- $a<0$: no solution,
- $a=0$: $x\ge0$,
- $a>0$: $x=-a$ or $x=a^2-a$.

Comment: Your way of writing it out is more convincing than my own. Thank you!

Comment: @mrtaurho: you are welcome. Avoiding the second squaring makes it more straightforward I guess.

Answer (score 2):

You solution is right, but you can make it easier.

You got $a\geq0$ and the domain $x\geq-a$.

Thus, roots $-a$ and $a^2-a$ are both valid without checking.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Hence we got $-a\geqslant-a\implies0\geqslant0$ and $-a+a^2\geqslant-a\implies a^2\geqslant0$ we are in no need of further verification since both inequalities hold for all real $a$? Any idea why it should be restricted to $a=0$ (which seems to be false)?

Comment: For $a=0$ we get $|x|=x$ or  $x\geq0$ which you got also from $x\geq-a$. $-a+a^2\geq-a$ says that $-a+a^2$ is valid.

Comment: So there is no need for this restriction at all. Thank you for your time :)